# Parsing a GenBank file with multiple gene entries

Tags: python, text-processing, genbank

Basically a GenBank file consists of gene entries (announced by 'gene') followed by its corresponding 'CDS' entry (only one per gene) like the two shown here below. I would like to extract part of the data from the input file shown below according to the following rules and print it in the terminal.

- There are two blocks of gene data shown below. I want to extract part of both blocks.
- The extracted text for each block starts with a line that contains spaces at the beginning of the line followed by `gene`
- The extracted text for each block ends with a line that contains `/db_xref="GeneID`
- The perl and awk tags are just suggestions. An answer can use a different program(s).

Input file (source: [biotech](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21888945)):

```
     gene            complement(8972..9094)
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0004"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278619"
     CDS             complement(8972..9094)
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0004"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /transl_table=11
                     /product="hypothetical protein"
                     /protein_id="YP_002474657.1"
                     /db_xref="GI:219870282"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278619"
                     /translation="MYYKALAHFLPTLSTMQNILSKSPLSLDFRLLFLAFIDKR"
     gene            9632..11416
                     /gene="frdA"
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0005"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278620"
     CDS             9632..11416
                     /gene="frdA"
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0005"
                     /note="part of four member fumarate reductase enzyme
                     complex FrdABCD which catalyzes the reduction of fumarate
                     to succinate during anaerobic respiration; FrdAB are the
                     catalytic subcomplex consisting of a flavoprotein subunit
                     and an iron-sulfur subunit, respectively; FrdCD are the
                     membrane components which interact with quinone and are
                     involved in electron transfer; the catalytic subunits are
                     similar to succinate dehydrogenase SdhAB"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /transl_table=11
                     /product="fumarate reductase flavoprotein subunit"
                     /protein_id="YP_002474658.1"
                     /db_xref="GI:219870283"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278620"
                     /translation="MQTVNVDVAIVGAGGGGLRAAIAAAEANPNLKIALISKVYPMRS
                     HTVAAEGGAAAVAKEEDSYDKHFHDTVAGGDWLCEQDVVEYFVEHSPVEMTQLERWGC
                     PWSRKADGDVNVRRFGGMKIERTWFAADKTGFHLLHTLFQTSIKYPQIIRFDEHFVVD
                     ILVDDGQVRGCVAMNMMEGTFVQINANAVVIATGGGCRAYRFNTNGGIVTGDGLSMAY
                     RHGVPLRDMEFVQYHPTGLPNTGILMTEGCRGEGGILVNKDGYRYLQDYGLGPETPVG
                     KPENKYMELGPRDKVSQAFWQEWRKGNTLKTAKGVDVVHLDLRHLGEKYLHERLPFIC
                     ELAQAYEGVDPAKAPIPVRPVVHYTMGGIEVDQHAETCIKGLFAVGECASSGLHGANR
                     LGSNSLAELVVFGKVAGEMAAKRAVEATARNQAVIDAQAKDVLERVYALARQEGEESW
                     SQIRNEMGDSMEEGCGIYRTQESMEKTVAKIAELKERYKRIKVKDSSSVFNTDLLYKI
                     ELGYILDVAQSISSSAVERKESRGAHQRLDYVERDDVNYLKHTLAFYNADGTPTIKYS
                     DVKITKSQPAKRVYGAEAEAQEAAAKKE"
```

Desired output:

```
     gene            complement(8972..9094)
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0004"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278619"
     CDS             complement(8972..9094)
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0004"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /transl_table=11
                     /product="hypothetical protein"
                     /protein_id="YP_002474657.1"
                     /db_xref="GI:219870282"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278619"
     gene            9632..11416
                     /gene="frdA"
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0005"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278620"
     CDS             9632..11416
                     /gene="frdA"
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0005"
                     /note="part of four member fumarate reductase enzyme
                     complex FrdABCD which catalyzes the reduction of fumarate
                     to succinate during anaerobic respiration; FrdAB are the
                     catalytic subcomplex consisting of a flavoprotein subunit
                     and an iron-sulfur subunit, respectively; FrdCD are the
                     membrane components which interact with quinone and are
                     involved in electron transfer; the catalytic subunits are
                     similar to succinate dehydrogenase SdhAB"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /transl_table=11
                     /product="fumarate reductase flavoprotein subunit"
                     /protein_id="YP_002474658.1"
                     /db_xref="GI:219870283"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278620"
```

I tried using `pcregrep --multiline .*'START-SEARCH-TERM.*(\n|.)*END-SEARCH-TERM' path/to/SOURCE-FILE`. I installed pcregrep (grep utility that uses Perl-style regexps) in Ubuntu with `sudo apt install pcregrep`. I also installed Biopython with `sudo apt install python3-biopython` and ran the Simple GenBank parsing example from *Biopython Tutorial and Cookbook*.

Comment: I would strongly suggest simply using biopython, bioruby or biojulia etc. These libraries are really good for extracting data from genbank files. You tagged perl, [bioperl](https://bioperl.org/) can definitely do it, but Perl is a dying language and bioperl is not straightforward to install IIRC from 10 years ago —but worth a try.

Comment: @MatteoFerla take that back! Just because young whippersnappers today don't appreciate the power and beauty of Perl does not make it a dying language! Them's fighting words! :P

Comment: Yeah agreed, code is code. Two things will continue Perl in any age, regex and Perl one liners (definitely stylish). Have you ever heard of a Python one-lliner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use grep for this purpose as shown below,

```
grep -v /translation bio.txt | grep -B100000000 /db_xref= > output_file.txt
```

Just make sure that you keep the number with B bigger than the number of lines of your file.

If you print the contents of the above file you get your desired output as given below,

```
:~$ cat output_file.txt 
gene            complement(8972..9094)
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0004"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278619"
     CDS             complement(8972..9094)
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0004"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /transl_table=11
                     /product="hypothetical protein"
                     /protein_id="YP_002474657.1"
                     /db_xref="GI:219870282"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278619"
     gene            9632..11416
                     /gene="frdA"
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0005"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278620"
     CDS             9632..11416
                     /gene="frdA"
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0005"
                     /note="part of four member fumarate reductase enzyme
                     complex FrdABCD which catalyzes the reduction of fumarate
                     to succinate during anaerobic respiration; FrdAB are the
                     catalytic subcomplex consisting of a flavoprotein subunit
                     and an iron-sulfur subunit, respectively; FrdCD are the
                     membrane components which interact with quinone and are
                     involved in electron transfer; the catalytic subunits are
                     similar to succinate dehydrogenase SdhAB"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /transl_table=11
                     /product="fumarate reductase flavoprotein subunit"
                     /protein_id="YP_002474658.1"
                     /db_xref="GI:219870283"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278620"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^ {5}\w/{a=1} /\/translation/{a=0}a' file.gb 
     gene            complement(8972..9094)
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0004"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278619"
     CDS             complement(8972..9094)
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0004"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /transl_table=11
                     /product="hypothetical protein"
                     /protein_id="YP_002474657.1"
                     /db_xref="GI:219870282"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278619"
     gene            9632..11416
                     /gene="frdA"
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0005"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278620"
     CDS             9632..11416
                     /gene="frdA"
                     /locus_tag="HAPS_0005"
                     /note="part of four member fumarate reductase enzyme
                     complex FrdABCD which catalyzes the reduction of fumarate
                     to succinate during anaerobic respiration; FrdAB are the
                     catalytic subcomplex consisting of a flavoprotein subunit
                     and an iron-sulfur subunit, respectively; FrdCD are the
                     membrane components which interact with quinone and are
                     involved in electron transfer; the catalytic subunits are
                     similar to succinate dehydrogenase SdhAB"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /transl_table=11
                     /product="fumarate reductase flavoprotein subunit"
                     /protein_id="YP_002474658.1"
                     /db_xref="GI:219870283"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:7278620"
```

The idea here is to set `a` to `1` if this line starts with 5 spaces followed by a word character. Then, we set `a` back to `0` if this line matches `/translation`. The default action for `awk` when an expression evaluates to true (not 0) is to print, therefore the final `a` will cause all lines read while `a` is not 0 to be printed, effectively removing everything after each `/translation` line.

A more easily understandable version of the same code would be:

```
awk '{ 
        if(/^ {5}\w/){
            a=1
        }
        if(/\/translation/){
            a=0
        }
        if(a==1){
            print
        }
    }' file.gb
```

Comment: @karel it prints `/db_xref="GI:219870283"` but not `/db_xref="GeneID:7278620"`.

Comment: @karel see update. Awk to the rescue!